# Show column heading only in drill down

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have created a crystal report with a number of items in an invoice. I have grouped the details based on the invoice number & suppressed the detail section with `Drill-Down`.

The problem is I need the column headers to be displayed only in Drill-Down mode. Not when it's displaying just the summaries. How can I hide the column headings ?

I have found several sort of hack like solutions, but is there a standard way/feature in CR to do this?

Comment: How abt a sub report

Comment: but I need the drill down to give the users the option to expand the report only if they want to.

Comment: ok so what is the problem?

Comment: I tried a sub-report, but can't quite get around it. I have two tables one which contains the products in the invoice & another table containing a summary of the invoice itself. Pls tell me how to go about creating it.

Comment: Ok. I created a sub-report & added it into a separate detail section. Now the detail section is divided into a & b. But the details are displayed regardless whether the user drilled down or not. And I can't enable the drill down option because its disabled in the section expert.

Comment: you are using a sub report.... if the requirement that subreport should display only when user needs then why don't you place in report footer as if you place in details it runs for all records....

Comment: yes I need it to run for each & every record. Because in the report I display the invoices & their totals initially & after expanding a particular invoice I want to show the items/products tagged to that invoice. With a sub-report I can't make it like a drill down.

Comment: I have a though where I have implemented similar requirement few years back... what you do.. create a group with `Invoice` and place  a sub report to show the items inside the invoice in that sub report.. and make sure to create a same grouping structure in sub report aswell... now pass the invoice to the grouping of the sub report and hide the sub report section.... hope it helps